# Multisites with one host using htaccess. Need to create an images folder rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have one hosting account that I am running using to run multiple sites, masterhost.com. Under masterhost.com I have site1.com, site2.com, etc... and am using this piece of code in the masterhost directory to reroute the domain request from the masterhost directory to the site1 directory.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site1.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site1/$1/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site1.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ site1/index.php
```

However Joomla on site1.com is having some issues with with this, and is routing the default images path back to masterhost.com/images.

Is there a rewrite I could use that would recognize any request http://www.site1.com/images and write it to http://www.masterhost.com/site1/images?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is these two lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Basically, if the image exists on mainsite.com, these rules will prevent the request from being redirected to site1. So, for example, if you have mainsite.com/img/logo.png and site1.com/img/logo.png, site1.com would show the logo for mainsite.com.

Also, with this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site1/$1/
```

I don't believe the trailing slash should be there.

Finally, you didn't ask about it, but the last rule probably also doesn't work? If it does, removing the !-f and !-d checks above will break it. This would be because if a user requests site1.com/, the first rule redirects that to /site1/, which will never match the rule `^(/)?$`. So, that rule needs to be changed to:

```
RewriteRule ^site1(/)?$ site1/index.php
```

You may or may not need a slash between ^ and site1 in that rule, depending on your RewriteBase directive.